# Extract a public key from certificate

Tags: python, cryptography, x509

I'm trying to extract a public key from my certificate but i keep getting this error: ValueError: RSA key format is not supported.. Below is my code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

bob_crt = 'bob.crt'

public_key = RSA.import_key(bob_crt)
if isinstance(public_key, RSA.RsaKey):
    print("RSA public key")
else:
    print("Other key")
```

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This is the certififcate, its a x.509. Do i convert it to a PEM? I'm really confused. Any help would be great. I'm using Python.

Error is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\test\encryption\encrypt.py", line 91, in <module>
    public_key = RSA.import_key(bob_crt)
  File "C:\Users\venv\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 791, in import_key
    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks

Comment: can you add the traceback?

Comment: @AntonChernyshov I've added it in

Comment: @Robert ok i understand. How would that be done?

Comment: @Topaco I've just ran the code from your link. The outcome shows a public key.

Comment: @Topaco That is the complete code i have. I've been tasked to extract a public key from the certificate.

Comment: @Topaco i think i have to load the certificate and the certificate isnt PEM which makes it harder. I'll have to find a way to load the certificate then extract the key. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for the advice. Thats what im doing now. I need to load it before extracting the key. Thats probably why ive got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RSA.import_key` expects the content, not the filename. If you read the content first, your script works.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

with open("bob.crt") as f:
    bob_crt = f.read()

public_key = RSA.import_key(bob_crt)
if isinstance(public_key, RSA.RsaKey):
    print(public_key.export_key())
else:
    print("Other key")
```

Comment: I don't see the extraction of the public key.

Comment: @coder edited an answer